# Custom List Adapter is getting the same Object

Tags: java, android, listview, listadapter

I am trying to get a list of users using a GET method and displaying them on a list view. Stranglely the custome list view I am using is populating the list view with the last object in the array list. This question might have been asked before. But I can not get any proper replies. Appologies in advance. 
Following is excerpt from my main class.

```
String tag_string_req = "req_search";

StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Method.POST,
    AppConfig.searchUrl, new Response.Listener<String>() {

  @Override
  public void onResponse(String response) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Search Response: " + response.toString());
    hidePDialog();
    // for(int i=0;i<response.length();i++) {
    try {
      JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
      boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");

      // Check for error node in json
      if (!error) {
        // user successfully logged in
        // Create login session

        // Now store the user in SQLite
        Donors donor = new Donors();
        // String uid = jObj.getString("uid");

        JSONArray user = jObj.getJSONArray("users");

        for (int i = 0; i < user.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject ja = user.getJSONObject(i);
          donor.setId(Integer.parseInt(ja.getString("id")));
          donor.setName(ja.getString("name"));
          donor.setPhone(ja.getString("phone"));

          System.out.println(
              "*********************************************************" + Integer
                  .parseInt(ja.getString("id")) + " " + ja.getString("name") + " " + ja
                  .getString("phone"));
          donorsList.add(donor);
        }

        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

      } else {
        // Error in login. Get the error message
        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("message");
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
            errorMsg, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

      }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
      // JSON error
      e.printStackTrace();
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Json error: " + e.getMessage(),
          Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

  }


}, new Response.ErrorListener() {

  @Override
  public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Search Error: " + error.getMessage());
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
        error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    hidePDialog();
  }
}) {

  @Override
  protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
    // Posting parameters to login url
    Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
    System.out.println(
        "*********************************************************" + distance + " " + donorLat
            + " " + donorLong + " " + bloodGroup);

    params.put("distance", distance);
    params.put("origin_lat", donorLat);
    params.put("origin_long", donorLong);
    params.put("blood_group", bloodGroup);

    return params;
  }

};

// Adding request to request queue
AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq, tag_string_req);
```

And this is the List Adapter.

```
public class CustomListAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
private Activity activity;
private LayoutInflater inflater;
private List<Donors> donorItems;
public CustomListAdapter(Activity activity, List<Donors> donorItems) {
this.activity = activity;
this.donorItems = donorItems;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
return donorItems.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int location) {
return donorItems.get(location);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

if (inflater == null)
  inflater = (LayoutInflater) activity
      .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
if (convertView == null)
  convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.list_row, null);

;
TextView title = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.title);
ImageButton btnText = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnText);
ImageButton btnCall = (ImageButton) convertView.findViewById(R.id.btnCall);

// getting movie data for the row
Donors d = donorItems.get(position);
System.out.println("--------------------"+d);


// title
title.setText(d.getName());


return convertView;
}

}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Found the error. Inititalized the object outside of for loop. It should be like this. Thanks.

```
for (int i = 0; i < user.length(); i++) {
          JSONObject ja = user.getJSONObject(i);
          Donors donor = new Donors();
          donor.setId(Integer.parseInt(ja.getString("id")));
          donor.setName(ja.getString("name"));
          donor.setPhone(ja.getString("phone"));

          System.out.println(
              "*********************************************************" + Integer
                  .parseInt(ja.getString("id")) + " " + ja.getString("name") + " " + ja
                  .getString("phone"));
          donorsList.add(donor);
          System.out.println(donor);
        }
```